# How can Postgres's sequence be broken?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I have a question. It is, probably, theoretical. I can't understand how I break value in sequence, that increments `id` field of table. I have one database server and 5 clients. They write some data to this table at same time during several hours. Data can contains some thousands of entries.

So... sometimes sequence can be broken. I mean that it has current value, that doesn't less than maximum value of `id` field and as result I get an error after `INSERT`, related to existing `id` value.

E. g. Sometimes I have a case, when the table has entry with `id`, that greater than current value of `sequence`, which is responsible for returning values for `id` field for new entries. And this current value can be equal `id` of existing entry.

I fix this on the client side. I handle the error by query

```
SELECT setval('table_id_seq', COALESCE((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM table), 1), false);
```

But I want to know how to prevent reason of this error.

I have postgresql 9.5, started inside linux container (Docker).

Comment: It is not an error. Serials/sequences are not guaranteed to be gap-free. Just don't *assume* they are gap free.

Comment: I understand this. But sometimes sequence's current value can be less than maximal id.

Comment: If you (or your application programs) never assign to the sequence or to the target column, this cannot happen. (until wrap-around, of course)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your sequence got explicitly set.  `setval` can do this if you set your sequence to a value less than your current max id.  Then the default value conflicts with an existing value and you get an error.

A second thing that can happen is you can explicitly add an id that has a greater value.  In which case, the sequence is evaluated only if no value is provided for the column and it ends up behind.

So in these cases, make sure you never `INSERT` an explicit id and never call `setval` unintentionally.  Then the error should never happen (you can get gaps in the ids but you won't get errors of conflicts).

Comment: It appears I've described my issue not quite clear. My bad. I try to clarify.
I've added `setval` when I've detected that, the sequence can be broken sometimes. E.g. I've found this issue, and after this I've added `setval`. It works only when query is finished with error.
Also I have no place, where I point id explicitly.

Comment: How sure are you that nothing is inserting an explicit id?  One thing I have seen happen many times is COPY commands that bring in a table with an ID but fail to set the sequence after.  This is particularly common when people roll their own logical backup solutions.

Comment: BTW I have *never* see sequences get behind without explicit ids or setval's.

Comment: I've found the reason of this strange behavior. Value of sequence was incrented

Comment: I've found the reason of this strange behavior. Value of sequence was incremented unexpected every time when was processed `DO NOTHING`. It was unexpected because I didn't point fields that should be checked for DO NOTHING. After UPSERT that does nothing value of sequence incremented and it is reason of gaps in id values. By another words it was fault of my application not Postgresql server.

Comment: Yeah, that's because the default is evaluated before the rule or trigger is fired.

Comment: Re-reading there's one thing I don't understand.  Extra increments should not cause this error.  You must have some values higher than your current maximum in the table.